# Difference in Generated Prisma Client?

Tags: javascript, npm, nestjs, package.json, prisma

I have two `nestJS` projects and I am importing following dependency in both of them

`import { Prisma } from "@prisma/client";`

### Project 1

`@prisma/client` is included as `devdependency` only and the `import` is not working for me.
Error is `Module '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'Prisma'.ts(2305)`

### Project 2

`@prisma/client` is included as `dependency` only and the import not working fine.

---

I looked at the `@prisma/client` generated code(By looking at `index.d.ts`) and there is a difference between both of projects.

Now I am curious it is just happening because of being included as devdependency or there is something else i am missing ?

Prisma Client version is same across both the projects : `"@prisma/client": "3.15.2"`

Comment: Have you executed `npx prisma generate` before importing?

Comment: Nope i didn't do that and i thought prisma client is generated automatically or not sure if this command is being run somewhere in the project ?

Comment: You would need to invoke `npx prisma generate` command before running your app

Comment: I tried that but it didn't have any effect to the original problem.

Comment: Here's an official example of using Prisma with NestJS, this might help you in identifying root cause of the issue: https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/latest/typescript/rest-nestjs/src